# Datalist without repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am new at `asp.net`. I have created a table with `datalist`, which contains information from database. The problem is that table is repated for each row. I have as mush tables as rows data. I don't want this, I want only 1 table which contains all rows.
How can I do this?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DataList.aspx.cs" Inherits="DataList" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage2.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="content1" ContentPlaceholderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
    <asp:DataList ID="datalist1" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="Datalist1_ItemCommand"  
        oneditcommand="Datalist1_EditCommand" oncancelcommand="datalist1_CancelCommand" 
        onupdatecommand="datalist1_UpdateCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>      
        <article class="module width_12_quarter">
        <header><h3 class="tabs_involved">Artikujt</h3>
        </header>
        <div class="tab_container">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0"> 
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Tema</th>            
                    <th>Keywords</th>
                    <th>Kategoria</th>
                    <th>Departamenti</th>
                <tr> 
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblTema" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Tema") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LabelKeywords" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Keywords") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LabelKategoria" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Kategoria_Id") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Departamenti_Id") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"/></td>
                </tr> 
                </tbody>  
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </article>
        </ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <article class="module width_3_quarter">
        <header><h3 class="tabs_involved">Artikujt</h3>
        </header>
        <div class="tab_container">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0"> 
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Tema</th>            
                    <th>Keywords</th>
                    <th>Kategoria</th>
                    <th>Departamenti</th>
                <tr> 
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="etxtId" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Id") %>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="etxtTema" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Tema") %>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                   <td><asp:TextBox ID="etxtKeywords" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Keywords") %>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="etxtKategoria" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Kategoria_Id") %>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="etxtDepartamenti" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Departamenti_Id") %>'></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"/></td>           
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"/></td>      
                </tr>
                </tbody>  
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </article>
</EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you please post your current code so other can help?

Comment: just edited my question with the code.

Comment: @ huMpty duMpt any idea?

Comment: Try moving creating table outside `ItemTemplate`. Just do  `<tr>` and `<td>` within the `ItemTemplate`. Otherwise for each data row it will create the table

Comment: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList' does not have a public property named 'article'. shows this error